# Pause/resume CSS animation with easing function

Tags: css, css-animations

I'd like to pause and resume, ideally by addition and removal of a CSS class, a continuous CSS animation such as a linear rotation.

I've set up an example of a continuous animation which can be paused by flipping the `animation-play-state`:

```css
.spinner.inactive {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyebr5fz/)

However, when the pause is applied, the animation instantly stops. Instead, I'd like the animation to slow down over the course of an ease-in-out easing function, and do the same when the animation is resumed.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ne7gqmsu/1/ Only possible for max. 180deg rotations (if ofc. you want the same rotations). The problem with more than 180deg is that it doesn't remember where the previous has ended so it resets, i.e. jumps back to 0%.

Comment: "it doesn't remember where the previous has ended" - yes, that's the point of this question

Comment: This is CSS not JS...

Comment: Sure, I didn't explicitly state it, but I think it's fairly natural to assume that an environment that has access to CSS also has access to JS - especially given that the jsfiddle also uses JS to add/remove the class.